# I want to Start a Countdown Timer(Hour:Minute:Second) for my Quiz React App,How to start the timer Only when I select a Subject?

Tags: javascript, mern

```js
//This function is called when I select a Subject//

const StartTimer =()=>{
useEffect(() => {
      const secondsCounter =
        seconds > 0 &&
        setInterval(() => setSeconds(seconds - 1), 1000);
      return () => clearInterval(secondsCounter);
    }, [seconds]);
   
    //seconds == 60 (when seconds == 0)
    useEffect(() => {
      return () => setSeconds(2);
    }, [seconds === 0 && minutes > 0 && !timeDone]);
    
    //MINUTES
    //Minutes 60 -> 0  (when seconds == 0)
    useEffect(() => {
      return () => setMinutes(minutes - 1);
    }, [seconds === 0 && minutes > 0]);
    

    // Minutes == 60 (when minutes == 0)
    useEffect(() => {
      return () => setMinutes(2);
    }, [minutes === 0 && hours > 0 && !timeDone]);

    //HOURS
    //hours 24 => 0 (when minutes == 0)
    useEffect(() => {
      return () => setHours(hours - 1);
    }, [minutes === 0 && hours > 0 && !timeDone]);

    //DONE
    useEffect(() => {
      return () => {
        setDone(true);
        console.log('STOP');
        history.push('/');
      };
    }, [hours === 0 && minutes === 0 && seconds === 0]);
  };
}

 <p>Remaining Time: {hours} :{minutes}: {seconds}</p>
```

Comment: Hi, I think you are not using `useEffect`s as they are intended. The second parameter is not a condition for when to execute the effect, it is an array of dependencies. React checks if any of these dependencies changed and when any of them do, it runs the effect.

As I wrote this comment I think I understood what you tried to do and now I think it might be genious.

Comment: it finally worked, I just use  setSeconds(false) as initial state. Previously I use setSeconds(0) as initial state. Thanks for the help.